# I am facing the some error in my ejs file can someone please assist me?

Tags: node.js, ejs

The error I am facing is as follows:

[image]

I have the following code written in server.js file. What am I doing wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var instagram = require('instagram-node').instagram();
const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

instagram.use({
    client_id:'1063599834134140',
    client_secret:'66cbe60a931310beb7a8cf6d4ec7a12f '
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //
    instagram.media_popular(function(err, medias, remaining, limit)
    {
        res.render('pages/index', {grams: medias});
    });
});

app.listen(8080, function(err)
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log("Error Occured");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("listening on port 8080");
    }
});
```

And the following is index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div class="row">
    <% grams.forEach(function(true){ %>
        <div class="instagram-pic col-sm-3">
            <a href="<%= gram.link %>" target="_blank">
                <img src="<%= gram.images.standard_resolution.url %>" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="instagram-bar">
            <div class="likes">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
            <%= gram.likes.count %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comments">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
            <%= gram.comments.count %>
        </div>
    <%  })  %>
    </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd guess it's your include, since the path should likely be enclosed in quotes. I don't know ejs myself though. But as a general tip, if you're facing an error you cannot at all pinpoint, try commenting out portions of your program to circle in on the error. Just dumping code here and a screen shot of an error without saying what you've tried so far is somewhat arrogant, especially when demanding help ASAP... Perhaps you should try to learn to debug rather than just getting the answer? "Give a man a fish" vs "Teach a man how to fish" you know?

Comment: Please don't take pictures of text, and if you for some reason need to do that, don't take picture of the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your includes are wrong. Using the [ejs-lint](https://github.com/ryanzim/ejs-lint) package that your error message references gives the following:

```
Unexpected token (4:17) in asdf.ejs
    <% include ../partials/head %>
```

In looking at some [ejs docs](https://ejs.co/#docs), the syntax they give for include is:

> Includes are relative to the template with the include call. (This requires the 'filename' option.) For example if you have "./views/users.ejs" and "./views/user/show.ejs" you would use `<%- include('user/show'); %>`.

> You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (<%-) with your include to avoid double-escaping the HTML output.

So in your case that would be

```
<%- include('../partials/head') %>
```

And of course, same for your other includes.

Also for future reference, it would be way better to copy/paste the error text into a code block in your question, instead of linking a screen shot.